# Force ld to look for libSM.so in the correct place

Tags: c++, gcc, hyperlink, ld, lib

One of the targets in my Makefile depends on `libSM.so` but ld for some reason looks inside `/usr/Lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/..`, finds an incompatible (32-bit) version and bails. I have the correct version in `/lib64` but `-L/lib64` did not help.

How do I force ld to take the version under `/lib64`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply pass that lib on cmd line:

```
gcc a.o b.o /usr/Lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libSM.so ...
```